# How does conversion to BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY work?

Tags: java, graphics

In Java one can load an image containing multiple colors into an BufferedImage object with color space BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, the image is then in black/white. What I am wondering about is how the "recoloring" to black/white is done: Is each pixel changed independently from the other pixels, e.g. by just looking if the color of the current pixel is more similar to black than white, or are the neighbouring pixel somehow taken into consideration?

The documentation BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY of states:

```
When color data is stored in an image of this type, the closest color in 
the colormap is determined by the IndexColorModel and the resulting index 
is stored.
```

I assume this means that the color of each pixel is changed independently from the colors of its neighbouring pixels or does this quote mean something else? I am not very familiar with imaging things, that's why I am wondering if I am right with that.

Comment: You are correct in your interpretation. Each pixel is handled individually.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation :-)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no scaling involved, the transform should be one-to-one. In the case of transforming from color to black and white, it could be done by calculating the grayscale value of the pixel color like this `Gray = 0.299×Red + 0.587×Green + 0.114×Blue` and apply a threshold say 128 to the result. If it's larger than 128, make it white; otherwise, make it black. Suppose the first entry in the colormap is black and the second one is white, then pixels with grayscale value larger than 128 will be given entry index 1 and other pixels will be given index 0;

**Note:** 
A BufferedImage of type BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY has an IndexColorModel without alpha. It represents an opaque byte-packed 1, 2, or 4 bit image, namely 2-color, 4-color, and 16-color images with a colormap of appropriate color entries. If you construct a BufferedImage without passing a IndexColorModel, a default back-n-white colormap is createde with two entries {0, 0, 0} and {255, 255, 255}. But this is not restricted to black and white, you can choose any two colors from default sRGB ColorSpace and create a IndexColorModel to pass to the BuffereImage constructor. You can create 4-color and 16-color images the same way using IndexColorModel.